# JQuery Selector - How to Check if Specific Path Exists?

Tags: jquery

I have this sample HTML,

```
<ul id=1>
    <li>
        <select class='test1'>test1</select>
    </li>
    <li>
         <select class='test222'>test222</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>
              <select class='test222'>test222</select>
           </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test3'>test3</select>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id=2>
    <li>
        <select class='test11'>test11</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test12'>test13</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test13'>test13</select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I have a javascript variable

```
var $cursor = $("ul#1"); // this variable is dynamic; This cannot be modified
```

My goal is how do I check if specific path exists?

I want to check if this path exists,

```
$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222
```

Not this one,

```
$cursor > li > select.test222
```

I am getting error when doing this

```
$($cursor+" > li > ul > li select.test222");
```

Thank You,

Comment: What error are you getting? and you are missing `" "` around your ids'

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] > ul > li select.test222

Comment: `if ($('> li > ul > li select.test222', $cursor).length) { alert('exists!'); }`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/t86p297w/)

Comment: @Don'tPanic can you post this as an answer? I keep forgetting you can change the target of a lookup - the second parameter is so rarely used.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, done. The question is really a dup IMO but I guess it combines 2 common questions, so might be useful in future.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) to target a selector to search another selector, instead of the document root.  So in this case, we can do:

```js
var $selector = $('> li > ul > li select.test222', $cursor);
```

And then it is just a matter of using [the standard way to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery) if that selector exists:

```js
if ($selector.length) {
    // Your specific selector path exists
    // ...
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/t86p297w/).

Comment: This is the equivalent of `$cursor.find(">li...` (one calls the other, so is just preference)

Comment: Can you add docs for `target a selector to another selector`, I always used find method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting $cursor as an element, where you actually just want the id

I added some variables to get the attribute, and use it in your selector, and check the length of the object.

If the object has length, then it exists.

```js
var cursor = $("ul#1"); // this variable is dynamic; This cannot be modified
var id = cursor.attr('id');
var elementToCheck = $("#"+id+" > li > ul > li select.test222").length;
if(elementToCheck){
  console.log('element exists');
} else {
  console.log('element does not exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=1>
    <li>
        <select class='test1'>test1</select>
    </li>
    <li>
         <select class='test222'>test222</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>
              <select class='test222'>test222</select>
           </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test3'>test3</select>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id=2>
    <li>
        <select class='test11'>test11</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test12'>test13</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test13'>test13</select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will not work if the `$cursor` element doesn't have an ID.

Comment: @VLAZ if the cursor element, does not have an id, then the path does not exist and it will return false, which was what the question was about.

Comment: I mean if the cursor element was defined as `$cursor = $('ul.first')` which presumably matches a single element. And that element doesn't have an ID.

Comment: @VLAZ true, but then it would also mean that the path requested does not exists, since it does not contain the ID - furthermore, the $cursor variable could not be modified according to the OP, and looking at the structure, I would say that it is safe to assume that the section he is working with will always have an ID - If this is (for example) a for loop, then why would the UL suddenly be missing an ID?

Comment: But you are right - if the structure of the data suddently changes to not have an id, then it would always return false. but `$cursor = $('ul.first')` would not brake it if the ul still has an id.

Comment: According to OP, the `$cursor` variable is dynamically generated, so it might technically be made to match any element, not only specifically `ul#1`.

Comment: @VLAZ, that depends on how it is generated - if this is generated to always pick one of the ULs, then it is fine. What other element on the page would have that same path generated - seems unlikly and unlogical to have another element on the page, which also contains the path `> li > ul > li select.test222`

Comment: If the structure of the `<ul>`s changes, then they could definitely have

Comment: if the structure changes, then the path doesn't exists....

Comment: But it should. Structure changes so the `<ul>`s don't have an ID and the `$cursor` changes to still target the correct element. The expanded selector could still match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to programmatically [traverse the tree using jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) by using [`$.children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

```js
var $cursor = $("ul#1"); // this variable is dynamic; This cannot be modified

//$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222
var elements = $cursor
  .children("li")
  .children("ul")
  .children("li")
  .children("select.test222");
  
console.log("$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222 exists:", elements.length > 0);

//$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test333
var elements2= $cursor
  .children("li")
  .children("ul")
  .children("li")
  .children("select.test333");
  
console.log("$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test333 exists:", elements2.length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=1>
    <li>
        <select class='test1'>test1</select>
    </li>
    <li>
         <select class='test222'>test222</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>
              <select class='test222'>test222</select>
           </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test3'>test3</select>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id=2>
    <li>
        <select class='test11'>test11</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test12'>test13</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test13'>test13</select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is what happens when the route isn't matched:

```js
var $cursor = $("ul#1"); // this variable is dynamic; This cannot be modified

//$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222
var elements = $cursor
  .children("li")
  .children("ul")
  .children("li")
  .children("select.test222");
  
console.log("$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222 exists:", elements.length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=1>
    <li>
        <select class='test1'>test1</select>
    </li>
    <li>
         <select class='test222'>test222</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>
              
           </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test3'>test3</select>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id=2>
    <li>
        <select class='test11'>test11</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test12'>test13</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test13'>test13</select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You could also use [`$.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and give it a selector, however, it matches *any* subtree, not anything that starts from the current element. So, it can work:

```js
var $cursor = $("ul#1"); // this variable is dynamic; This cannot be modified

//$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222
var elements = $cursor
  .find("li > ul > li > select.test222");
  
console.log("$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222 exists:", elements.length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=1>
    <li>
        <select class='test1'>test1</select>
    </li>
    <li>
         <select class='test222'>test222</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>
              <select class='test222'>test222</select>
           </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test3'>test3</select>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id=2>
    <li>
        <select class='test11'>test11</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test12'>test13</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test13'>test13</select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Beware that it might produce a false positive if you only expect these to be the children of the current element:

```js
var $cursor = $("ul#1"); // this variable is dynamic; This cannot be modified

//$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222
var elements = $cursor
  .find("li > ul > li > select.test222");
  
console.log("$cursor > li > ul > li > select.test222 exists:", elements.length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=1>
    <li>
        <select class='test1'>test1</select>
    </li>
    <li>
         <select class='test222'>test222</select>
    </li>
    <div> <!-- extra element, so now it's not a direct child of ul#1 -->
      <li>
          <ul>
             <li>
                <select class='test222'>test222</select>
             </li>
          </ul>        
      </li>
    </div>
    <li>
        <select class='test3'>test3</select>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id=2>
    <li>
        <select class='test11'>test11</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test12'>test13</select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class='test13'>test13</select>
    </li>
</ul>
```